# <BEA 101020> Weblogic 12.1.3.0 ,java..lang.IllegalstateException :NO WebApplicationContext found :NO ContextLoaderListener registered?

Tags: java, spring, deployment, migration, weblogic

We are migrating an application from weblogic 10.3 to 12.1.3.0.
it is a remote server we have to do these migration.

Please find the below background and my problem along with my workaround.

1)when I deploy the same .ear which is upand running in the 10.3 to 12.1.3.0 it is not atall deploying with Class notfound Exceptions even though the files are presented in APP-INF/Lib.so I have checked all the jars and they are in lib.still the same error persists,so I have left that and started building new ear with new version of java(we also need the java 1.8).

2)when I deploy the new ear into weblogic ,it got deployed but when I hit the URL ,it is giving the Below error similar to
**servlet failed with Exception
Java.lang.IllegalStateException :No webapplicationFound :no Context LoadListener registered?**
strong text
my work around :
1)when I went through web.xml I found

```
    context-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/applicationresouces.xml
        <param-value>classpath:/application-dao.xml
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/security.xml
      like wise we have 3 more files
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

2)ContextLoadListener also presented in the web.xml

### org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

but still I am getting the above error.what I am missing in it.?
and how the classpath:/*.xml files will be loaded? in the DEV environment?does we need to create them in the JVM classpath?
I really wondering what is going wrong.

Comment: I am new to weblogic and its configurations ,so please correct me if Any other peace of code will cause these error?so that I can look into that components also as per you guys suggestions

Comment: You are missing your web application, no contexClassLoader available.

Comment: Thanks for the response .I am not changing any code changes or configuration changes ,what ever the code that is running in the old environment,I just compiled with new java version and deployed it in to new environment.so how I can miss those configurations(as-is I am keeping all)

Comment: Please add the `web.xml` header and please clarify which spring version you are using. Also be aware that web logic ships (or shipped?) with its own version of spring, when shipping another version of Spring you would have to add a web logic specific deployment descriptor telling to prefer the classes from the lib over the the classes from the server.